# Android - Add a custom view to a component in a xml layout

Tags: android, xml, view

I have an abstract class extended from the class View, and 4 subclasses to perform a series of vectorial drawings. Then I have a layout with four Buttons and a View to show the drawings. Depending on which button is clicked, different figures should be drawn in that View. The problem is that when I click one button, the figures are drawn filling the entire screen, the buttons disappear. How could this problem be solved?

```
public abstract class DrawFiguresWithDimensions extends View{
    public DrawingFiguresWithDimensions(Context context)
    //...
}
public class DrawRectangleWithDimensions extends DrawFiguresWithDimensions {..}
public class DrawTWithDimensions extends DrawFiguresWithDimensions {..}
public class DrawDobleTWithDimensions extends DrawFiguresWithDimensions {..}
public class DrawBoxWithDimensions extends DrawFiguresWithDimensions {..}
```

Here is the "activity_main.xml":

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="10"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSecRec"
        android:text="Rec"
        android:onClick="btnSecRec"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSecT"
        android:text="T"
        android:onClick="btnSecT"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSecDobleT"
        android:text="DT"
        android:onClick="btnSecDobleT"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSecCajon"
        android:text="Box"
        android:onClick="btnSecCajon"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
<View class="com.tari.drawfigureswithdimensions.DrawFiguresWithDimensions"
    android:id="@+id/viewDatosSec"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

"MainActivity.java"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DrawRectangleWithDimensions sec1;
DrawTWithDimensions sec2;
DrawDoubleTWithDimensions sec3;
DrawBoxWithDimensions sec4;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void btnSecRec(View view){
    sec1 = new DrawRectangleWithDimensions(this);
    sec1.setFigure(10, 40);
    setContentView(sec1);
}
public void btnSecT(View view){
    sec2 = new DrawTWithDimensions(this);
    sec2.setFigure(100, 20, 20, 70);
    setContentView(sec2);
}
public void btnSecDobleT(View view){
    sec3 = new DrawDoubleTWithDimensions(this);
    sec3.setFigure(100, 20, 20, 90, 50, 25);
    setContentView(sec3);
}
public void btnSecCajon(View view){
    sec4 = new DrawBoxWithDimensions(this);
    sec4.setFigure(100, 20, 20, 80);
    setContentView(sec4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect to instantiate an abstract class by referencing it in your xml layout.

You'll need to specify a concrete implementation in order for it to work properly.

So, instead, you might provide a ViewGroup of some sort in your layout to serve as the parent for whatever concrete DrawFiguresWithDimensions implementation you want to show based on what button is pressed.

Then, dynamically remove the current child associated with your parent ViewGroup and add the one corresponding to your pressed button.

Essentially, you'll want to replace this in your activity_main.xml layout:

```
<View class="com.tari.drawfigureswithdimensions.DrawFiguresWithDimensions"
android:id="@+id/viewDatosSec"
android:layout_weight="8"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

with this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/viewDatosSec"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And then when handling the button click, do something like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.btnSecCajon)
    {
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewDatosSec);
        parent.removeAllViews();
        parent.addView(new DrawBoxWithDimensions(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Michael. I created a ViewGroup with the four DrawFiguresWithDimensions views in the layout, but I'm still stuck in how to implement the code dinamically. Could you tell me how to do it, for instance, in the  public void btnSecRec(View view){ }, using the DrawRectangleWithDimensions?

Comment: @David I've just updated my answer with more info about how you go about dynamically placing a view in a parent ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks Michael! that solved the problem! Thank you for being so specific, it's great for beginners like me.

Comment: Sure - glad to help.   Would you mind accepting my answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view will be instantiate as soon as the layout will be load so NO abstract class allowed !

Here an exemple to include a custom view in your xml.
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html